# IE Bug: SVG marker visible outside viewport

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I came across a bug in Internet Explorer 11 where a marker path is still visible even if an outer element got the overflow:hidden attribute.

Here is an [example of the described problem](https://plnkr.co/edit/a5rvz3KdIoGTclE7HiBu?p=preview) (need to be viewed in IE11)

Here is the Code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 440px; height: 495px; overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid red">
    <svg>
      <g transform="translate(413.209 51.1721) scale(0.514057)">
        <defs><marker id="end" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" fill-opacity="1" fill="#888" orient="auto" class="arrowhead"><path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z"></path></marker></defs>        
        <path marker-end="url(#end)" style="fill:transparent; opacity: 1; stroke: #000; stroke-opacity: 1;" d="M323.921875,-19.2421875H-465.20818355008544V961.2877197265625H-465.20818355008544V981.2877197265625"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Image of the problem:

[image: the red border is the outer div which has overflow:hidden]

What I expected is that the marker is hidden as well. Has anybody experienced the same before?

Somehow this only occurs if a zoom larger or smaller than 100% is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the following article about a similar problem on css3 transformations and overflow:hidden:

https://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/css3-transformations-showing-content-outside-overflowhidden-region-in-firefoxandroid/

There was the suggestion to use:

```
svg { opacity: 0.99; }
```

This solves the problem.

The reason why this works might be related to how the z-index works.
A good read on that topic can be found here:
https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/